# Upgrade MVC1 project to MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp-net-mvc-1

Is there a way to convert a ASP.Net MVC 1 project build in VS2008 to ASP.Net MVC 5 and VS2015?

I tried to just open it in VS 2015 but that gave the error "This project is incompatible with the current version of Visual Studio".

Comment: MVC 1 to MVC 5? Wow! On a serious note, you're best bet is to follow guides in order e.g. go from MVC 1 to MVC 2, then from MVC 2 to MVC 3, etc. I don't envy your task though. If it's a small enough project, I'd be more tempted to copy and paste the code from the MVC 1 project into a new MVC 5 project.

Comment: I totally agree, but who knows if there is not a tool out there for mel. Just dreaming...

Comment: There are no tools to go from 1 to 2 or 3 to 4 because each version includes significant changes in routing, base Controller classes etc.1 to 5 is a huge change - almost everything is different

Comment: Well. THAT sounds like fun :)

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to reference newer versions and update, eg:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2

.. however updating from MVC1 (especially if you cannot open the project) you probably don't want to manually install ASP.NET MVC installs etc (if that what I remember)

I would suggest creating a new MVC5 application, referencing MVC via Nuget etc and pulling in code as required. This will give you a chance to re-structure things and learn newer ways otherwise you my be fighting with MVC configuration and references.